# web pack css-loader generated css class names with react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap, css-loader

I'm using css-loader for web pack, and the configuration looks like this:

```
loaders: [
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?camelCase&modules')
}, ...]
```

And then in my jsx file I have something like this:

```
import styles from 'components/MyComponent/style.css'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            return <div className={styles.myComponent}>
                <Media>
                    <Media.Left>
                    ...
                    </Media.Left>
                    <Media.Body> 
                    ...
                    </Media.Body>
                </Media>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And in my `components/MyComponent/style.css` file I have something like:

```
.myComponent .media-left {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And so my problem is, `css-loader` will generate random ids for both `.myComponent` and `.media-left`, which is seriously annoying. Because `.media-left` is a bootstrap class and I want it just left alone. Is there a way to make `css-loader` only generate an id for the top level css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out. I need to use the global selector for every class that I want to remain global, something like this:

```
.myComponent :global(.media-left) {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have one loader for bootstrap and the other for the rest of your css, based on `test` config.

On another note, the `modules` part of your css-loader config is responsible random class names. You can use [localIdentName](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) config to format generated classnames to your liking.